# rails 5.1.4 assert_select 'li', is only checking for first li

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am working through Agile Web Development in Rails 5.1, I seem to be having issues with testing. The book says if I have markdown like

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>etc...</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
     <li>
       <%= item.quantity %> &times; <%= 
           item.product.title %>
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I should be able to write this text

```
assert_select 'li', '1 \u00d7 Programming Ruby 1.9'
```

and have it return :true, but it is only checking for the first li element,

```
Failure:LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_create_line_item [/Users/coreygibson/Documents/workspace/Depot/test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:27]:
<1 \u00d7 Programming Ruby 1.9> expected but was
<Home>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Is there a setting to fix this? or am I missing something? The book says this should work.

Comment: What do you see with `assert_select "1 x Programming Ruby 1.9''` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the issue in my code

```
assert_select 'li', '1 \u00d7 Programming Ruby 1.9'
```

needed to be

```
assert_select 'li', "1 \u00d7 Programming Ruby 1.9"
```

in order to correctly display the \u00d7 had to be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the book, but from the [`assert_select` docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select), it sounds like it's working as intended:

> If the first argument is an element, selects all matching elements starting from (and including) that element and all its **children** in depth-first order.
>   *(Emphasis mine)*

Since "Home" is inside a separate `ul` parent, I'm not sure, but I suspect it can't find the correct `li`. Try this:

```
assert_select 'ul' do
  assert_select 'li', '1 \u00d7 Programming Ruby 1.9'
end
```

Comment: I found my issue I needed double quotes for the \u00d7

Comment: Glad to hear it! You may want to add an answer and accept it, since mine was not so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Same newbie error here.

Replace single-quote with double-quote fix the issue.

Add some reasons here:

1. Single quotes can not hold/print escape sequences directly, while double quotes can. `\u00d7` need escaping to match the test result
   https://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/03/ruby-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes/
2. The asset_select assertion is true if **at least** one element selected. If no element found, the first found element will be printed in the error message. That's why we see `<Home>` as the actual result.
   https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select